# User-Profile-Form.tpl.php not working. Help!

Tags: 7, users, theming

I am not rendering any results. This is my template.php:

```
function fueldeluxe_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $items = array();

  /**
   *  Account edit Forms
   */

  $items['user_profile_form'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'template' => 'user-profile-form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'fueldeluxe') . '/templates'
  );

  return $items; 
}

function fueldeluxe_preprocess_user_profile_form(&$variables) {
  $variables['account'] = drupal_render($variables['form']['account']);
  $variables['picture'] = drupal_render($variables['form']['picture']);
}
```

This is my user-profile-form.tpl.php:

```
<div id="account-settings">

  <div id="profile">
    <?php echo $picture; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="account">
    <?php echo $account; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm trying to load the user profile field forms. However I'm not able to render any results. The page loads okay when I add dummy text but no account field forms.

Do I need a module for this to work?

Also what would the variable look like for calling the custom field added to a user?

Comment: Consider re-wording your questions title.  I would also recommend 'recapping' the question you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with what you're asking in the first portion of your question, but looking into the previous Stack Exchange page you referenced you can use the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module to quickly accomplish two column layouts for these forms.  You can also use [template overrides](http://drupal.org/node/350634) to change the layout of the registration pages.

If you're specifically looking to quickly implement a tabbed UI for the user profile, I believe the [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module may offer a [built-in](http://drupal.org/node/1074296) solution.

> "Also what would the variable look like for calling the custom field
>   added to a user?"

You may need to use [load_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7)() first to get a complete user object to access custom profile fields.

```
$account = user_load(<USER-ID>); //$node->uid or $user->uid
```

Comment: I edited to question for clarity.